# Pretty print s expressions from the command line

Tags: command-line-arguments, parsing, sexp

I've got a file containing an emacs s-expression and I want to pretty print it from the command line: Is there an easy way of doing this? Paranoia suggests I want to do as little parsing of this data as possible

Context (stack exchange loves context...): I'm doing some processing or org file data externally in a python process. I'm pushing out s-expressions and parsing them in python (with `sexpdata`) because this is easier than munging stuff into json in emacs.

I'm considering coding up my own parser, or using sexpdata to parse it, or trying to use `emacsclient -exec` or similar.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990052/lisp-code-s-expression-formatter, perhaps this is a duplicate... but I feel the command line requirements make this question distinct.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment (including an early stage one liner) because this one liner contained quite a misleading mistake and I couldn't edit it (inadvertently threw away parts of the pretty printed output). Although perhaps I should have summoned at admin instead. Relevant information is in my gist below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
emacsclient -e '(pp (with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents "my-file-containing sexp") (read (current-buffer))))'
```

The problem is that this will print a *string* (e.g., `"[foo\n bar]"`), so to see it on the screen you will need

```
echo -e $(emacsclient ...)
```

You can control the behavior of [`pp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html) with [many variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html).

Comment: Awesome. I've used a similar approach but with the `emacs --eval` and `(message` to work around emacsclient's limitiations. I specifically want to read from a file on the command line (I generate this output when by emacs library is in debug mode), so I don't need to use emacsclient to get emacs state. I like the `echo -e` hack...

Comment: Whoops: the first gist I posted had a thinko: See this gist for my solution. Run as `sexpretty.sh file.sexp` : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78faa02b66c7da10613011dda8d75a29

Comment: Yep just doing that (posted the other link first to avoid confusion / check the link worked).